# How can i get tinyMCE to handle blur consistently on an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, tinymce, tinymce-4

I currently trap the onBlur event in tinyMCE to perform an Ajax update everytime the editor loses focus:

```
tmced.on('blur', function (ed, evt) {
   tinyMCEAutoSave()
});
```

This works fine everywhere except on Safari on an iPad where the blur event seems to fire inconsistently. For example, it fires if I move the focus to another text input control, but not if I click on a button or a link.

Does anyone know how I can get consistent behaviour on an iPad?